# Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined': Importing and using function with return object containing async functions as properties

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6, promise

Here is an exported function in my `adapter.ts` file:

```
import type { Adapter } from "@lib/core/adapters";

export default function MyAdapter (): Adapter {
  return {
    async createUser (user: User) {
      ...
    },
    async findUserByEmail (email) {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

I'm importing the above in `route.ts` and trying to use it in a handler function:

```
import MyAdapter from "./adapter";

const adapter = MyAdapter();

export default async function handler(
  req: Request,
  res: Response
) {
  try {
    const profile = await adapter.findUserByEmail("john@doe.com");
    ...
  } catch (e) {}
}
```

When I do a `tsc`, I get this TypeScript error:

```
src/app/api/auth/signup/route.ts:22:37 - error TS2722: Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.

22         const profile = await adapter.findUserByEmail("john@doe.com");
                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I can "fix" this by initializing the `adapter` constant like so:

```
const adapter = new (MyAdapter as any)();
```

But this seems hacky, nor do I understand what's going on. Should the `MyAdapter` function be a class? I don't want to create a new instantiation if I don't have to.

Comment: What is the type of `Adapter` that you're importing from `@lib/core/adapters`? Because that's what defines the type of your `MyAdapter` return value, which apparently doesn't make `findUserByEmail` definitely not `undefined`. Are you sure you should be using that type, as opposed to just letting TypeScript infer?

Answer (score 0):

To address the issue, include an interface that informs the TypeScript compiler about the object being returned, which will contain the necessary functions for usage. Modify the adapter as follows:

```
import type { Adapter } from "@lib/core/adapters";

export interface IMyAdapter extends Adapter {
  createUser: (user: User) => any; // replace any with your Return Type
  findUserByEmail: (email: string) => any;
}

export default function MyAdapter (): IMyAdapter {
  return {
    async createUser (user: User) {
      ...
    },
    async findUserByEmail (email) {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```